# Web Forms - Multiple Select Query Results in a GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatables, dataset

I'm an extreme newbie.  Please bear with me.

I'm trying to populate a GridView with multiple resultsets.  I'm using a DataSet with mulitple DataTables.  This code has only 2 DataTables, but I will need to use more than 5 or maybe 10.

**ASP.NET 4.5.1 Web Forms w/ MSSQL**

**Method**

```
public DataSet GvTest()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            (
            "SELECT s.StudioName, i.Studio, i.UPC, i.Title, i.Price, i.Availability, i.Location, i.Qty " +
            "FROM tbl_Item i JOIN tbl_studio s ON i.Studio = s.StudioID WHERE i.Availability = 'T' and i.Qty > 0 ORDER BY i.Location; " +

            "SELECT d.UPC, SUM(d.Qty) FROM tbl_PROrderDetail d JOIN tbl_PROrder p ON d.OrderNo = p.OrderNo " +
            "WHERE p.Status = 'P' and p.Type = 'P' GROUP BY d.UPC;"

            , conn);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();

        DataTable dtTest = new DataTable();

        ds.Tables[0].Merge(ds.Tables[1]);
        dtTest = ds.Tables[0];

        return ds;
    }
}
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataModel dm = new DataModel();
    DataSet ds = dm.GvTest();
    GridBind(ds);
}

private void GridBind(DataSet ds)
{
    gvItemList.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    gvItemList.DataBind();
}
```

This code just generates the first SELECT result and then the second SELECT result right after.

What I need to do is add a new column to Tables[0], and the result set of Tables[1] fills the new column.

Row count of Tables[0] = 94
Row count of Tables[1] = 6800

I need 94 rows on my GridView, not 6800.  UPC is the connection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi KPark,  simply you can do this by changing the first SQL. Then your first SQL should be something like this.
        "SELECT [your new column],  s.StudioName, i.Studio, ....".  If you can share the database schema with few data records, I can help you to write the query.

Comment: I think you had the direction wrong. What you are looking for should be [a nested `GridView`](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=nested+gridview).

Comment: @ 蕭為元 // Thanks a lot.  Basically I need to fill the first column with query1, second column with query2 and etc... Do I still need a nested GridView?  Any other direction is welcome!